# Pivot Table In BigQuery Using Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, dynamic-pivot

I have a set of data (referenced the attached Excel sheet) that is unpivoted, which I am trying to pivot and convert the rows to columns.

In this case, the yellow headers are duplicated data. The green headers are what I want to convert from rows to columns, which will remove the duplication and thus pivot the data.

The top of the Excel sheet is what I have currently, the bottom is what I am wanting to get to.
I am using BigQuery standard SQL.

Any help is appreciated.

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skUCt.png)

Here is a short sample of what I have.

| catalog_number | manufacturer | region | region_price | region_catalog_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | nike | north | 10 | 123-n |
| 123 | nike | south | 8 | 123-s |

Here is a sample of what I want.

| catalog_number | manufacturer | region_north | region_north_price | region_north_catalog_number | region_south | region_south_price | region_south_catalog_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | nike | north | 10 | 123-n | south | 8 | 123-s |

Answer (score 0):

Consider below simple approach

```
select *
from your_table
pivot (
  any_value(region) region, 
  any_value(region_price) region_price, 
  any_value(region_catalog_number) region_catalog_number 
  for region in ('north', 'south')
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Have you tried? Did it work for you?

Comment: I tried this approach, and while it did achieve the desired output of converting rows to columns, the columns are all completely blank.